# Similarity measure using vectors in gensim

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I have a pair of word and semantic types of those words. I am trying to compute the relatedness measure between these two words using semantic types, for example: word1=king, type1=man, word2=queen, type2=woman
we can use gensim word_vectors.most_similar to get 'queen' from 'king-man+woman'. However, I am looking for similarity measure between vector represented by 'king-man+woman' and 'queen'.

I am looking for a solution to above (or)
way to calculate vector that is representative of 'king-man+woman' (and)
calculating similarity between two vectors using vector values in gensim (or)
 way to calculate simple mean of the projection weight vectors(i.e king-man+woman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the source code for the gensim `most_similar()` method, which is used to propose answers to such analogy questions. Specifically, when you try...

```
sims = wv_model.most_similar(positive=['king', 'woman'], negative=['man'])
```

...the top result will (in a sufficiently-trained model) often be 'queen' or similar. So, you can look at the source code to see exactly how it calculates the target combination of `wv('king') - wv('man') + wv('woman')`, before searching all known vectors for those closest vectors to that target. See...

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/5f6b28c538d7509138eb090c41917cb59e4709af/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L486

...and note that the local variable `mean` is the combination of the `positive` and `negative` values provided.

You might also find other methods there useful, either directly or as models for your own code, such as `distances()`...

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/5f6b28c538d7509138eb090c41917cb59e4709af/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L934

...or `n_similarity()`...

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/5f6b28c538d7509138eb090c41917cb59e4709af/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L1005